# Agregar Dataframe de Python a un Excel que ya tiene datos

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Estoy creando un código en el cual leo un archivo de Excel externo y deseo agregar esos datos a un nuevo archivo de Excel interno el cual ya tiene datos.

Deseo agregarlo en la ultima fila de la tabla que esta en Excel.

Únicamente falta ingresar los datos al nuevo Excel.

***CÓDIGO UTILIZADO***

```
lectura ='//SERVERARCH01/Diseproce/CONTROL DE PLAGAS/Control integrado de plagas/Control de plagas/traigo_data.xlsx'
wb=load_workbook(lectura,data_only=True)
ws= wb['BASE DE DATOS']
nombres= {key:value for key,value in ws.tables.items()}
print(nombres)
#num = 0
datos=[]
for entry,data_boundary in ws.tables.items():
    data= ws[data_boundary]
#    print(type(data))
#    print(data[0])
    content= [[cell.value for cell in ent]
              for ent in data
              ]
    header= content[0]
    rest= content[1:]
    df= pd.DataFrame(rest,columns=header)
    datos.append(df)
    #if num == 0:
        #print(df)
        #df0=df.copy()
    #num= num+1
for indice, df in enumerate(datos):
    df=df[df["Mes"]!="1-1900"]
    if indice == 0:
        df=df.iloc[:,[0,1,2,3,4,5]]
#    print(df)
#filtrar por indice
consumos=datos[0]
info=consumos[consumos["Mes"]!="1-1900"]
info=info.iloc[:,[0,1,2,4,5]]
consumos_mes = info.loc[info['Mes'].str.contains('8-2021')]
#https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yl4uMI8ioqw como filtrar dataframes.
print(info)
print(consumos_mes)
capturas=datos[1]
capturas=capturas[capturas["Mes"]!="1-1900"]
capturas=capturas.iloc[:,[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]]
capturas_mes = capturas.loc[capturas['Mes'].str.contains('8-2021')]
print(capturas_mes)
#aqui muestro el archivo de control interno a utilizar
archivo = '//SERVERARCH01/Diseproce/CONTROL DE PLAGAS/Control integrado de plagas/Control de plagas/Ingreso_data.xlsx'
#parametro= [5,6,7,8,9,10]
datos_registr = pd.read_excel(archivo, sheet_name='cont_roedores')
datos_registr.fillna("", inplace=True)
datos_registr.drop(datos_registr.filter(regex="Unname"), axis=1, inplace=True)
print(datos_registr)
print("este es el largo de la tabla:",len(datos_registr))
```

Comment: para algo existe el método `append()` ;D

Comment: apenas inicio en esto de programación y ya he intentado podrías ayudarme?

Answer (score 0):

Por ahora lo que se me ocurre es que leas el Excel, lo guardes en un DF y luego le hagas

```
pd.concat([df_excel, df_new_data])
```

No es lo mas eficiente pero solucionaría tu problema por ahora.

pdt: te diría que investigues la librería xlwings ya que esta te permitiría abrir el Excel y agregar datos, algo como esto

```
    import xlwings as xw

    arc_excel = xw.App(visible=False)
    libro = xw.books.open(Nombre_Excel)
    libro_datos = libro.sheets(Nombre_Hoja)

    libro_datos['A2'].options(pd.DataFrame, header=False, index=False, expand='table').value = df

    libro.save()
    arc_excel.quit()
    arc_excel.kill()
```

También se puede hacer con openpyxl pero considero esta la manera mas sencilla.